# sequence item 3: expected str instance, InMemoryUploadedFile found in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I got error while i tried to send images via email in django the error appear in this line

```
'id_card': form.cleaned_data.get['id_card'],
```

my form

```
class Verification(forms.Form):
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'required': "True"}))
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'required': "True"}))
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=150, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'required': "True"}))
id_card = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'custom-file-input', 'id': 'card-id', 'required': "True"}))
```

my views

```
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Verification(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        subject = 'request Verification'
        body = {
            'first_name': form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
            'last_name': form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
            'email': form.cleaned_data['email'],
            'id_card': form.cleaned_data['id_card'],
        }
        message = "\n".join(body.values())
        try:
            send_mail(subject, message, 'mohamed89salah98@gmail.com', ['mohamed89salah98@gmail.com'])
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return redirect('after-verification')
form = Verification()
return render(request, 'personal/verification.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: `"\n".join(body.values())` here `id_card` is an image (present in the dictionary `body`). You try to join that getting an error.

Comment: Thank you for your answe, do you know what's the solution?